# Implementation of strspn( )

Tags: c

The definition of library function `strspn` is:

```
size_t strspn(const char *str, const char *chars)

/* Return number of leading characters at the beginning of the string `str`
   which are all members of string `chars`. */
```

e.g. if `str` is `"fecxdy"` and `chars` is `"abcdef"` then the function would return `3`, since `f`, `e` and `c` all appear somewhere in `chars`, giving 3 leading characters of `str`, and `x` is the first character of `str` which is not a member of `chars`.

Could someone help me write an implementation of `strspn` in C. The only library function I am allowed to call from the implementation is `strlen`?

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Answer (score 10):

The basic idea is to step through the string, one character at a time, and test if it's in the character set.  If it's not, stop and return the answer.  In pseudocode, that would look like:

```
count = 0
for each character c in str
    if c is not in chars
        break
    count++
return count
```

The `if c is not in chars` test can be implemented by iterating through all of the characters of `chars` and testing if `c` matches any of the characters.  Note that this is not the fastest implementation, since it involves stepping through the `chars` string for each character in `str`.  A faster implementation would use a lookup table to test if `c is not in chars`.

Comment: A solution with a lookup table would not be faster in all cases, depending on the lengths of `chars` and `str`.

Comment: Lookup is constant time, assuming ASCII charset you can just create a 256 element array, set all values in the testset to 1, and just iterate over all chars in the string, looking up the value. You just iterate both string once, so it is O(n), with n being the larger one. Searching iteratively in both strings is O(n*m). This only is a problem if you are memory limited hard.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while going over old exams. You weren't allowed to use indexing or any standard functions. Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
size_t myStrspn(const char *str1, const char *str2){
  size_t i,j;
  i=0;

  while(*(str1+i)){
    j=0;
    while(*(str2+j)){
      if(*(str1+i) == *(str2+j)){
        break; //Found a match.
      }
      j++;
    }
    if(!*(str2+j)){
      return i; //No match found.
    }
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}

void main(){
  char s[] = "7803 Elm St.";
  int n = 0;
  n = myStrspn(s,"1234567890");
  printf("The number length is %d. \n",n);
}
```

Here's the solution from the exam:

```
#include<stdio.h>
size_t strspn(const char* cs, const char* ct) {
  size_t n;
  const char* p;
  for(n=0; *cs; cs++, n++) {
    for(p=ct; *p && *p != *cs; p++)
      ;
    if (!*p)
      break;
  }
  return n;
}
```

For loops made it much more compact.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be pretty fast

```
size_t strspn(const unsigned char *str, const unsigned char *chars){
    unsigned char ta[32]={0};
    size_t i;
    for(i=0;chars[i];++i)
        ta[chars[i]>>3]|=0x1<<(chars[i]%8);
    for(i=0;((ta[str[i]>>3]>>(str[i]%8))&0x1);++i);
    return i;
}
```

Thanks to others for sanity checks.

Comment: Brilliant! I would have done the same. The way it's working is to recognize there are only 256 characters possible. Each character can correspond to a position on a 256 wide bit array: 32 bytes.

Comment: @AleksanderAlekseev What's the bug?

Comment: @JL2210 he's right my solution was looking for characters not in the set instead of ones in it. change `if((ta[str[i]]>>(str[i]%8))&0x1) break;` to `if(!((ta[str[i]]>>(str[i]%8))&0x1)) break;` to fix

Comment: This does not work if `char` is signed and `chars` contains negative characters. Furthermore, `i` should be defined as a `size_t`. Last but not least, the function should return `i`, not `cnt - 1` which is always `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @user1424589: still incorrect: the arguments should have `const char *` type, not `unsigned char`, and you forgot to `>>3` the `str[i]` in `ta[str[i]]` in the second `for` loop.

Comment: on the >>3 you are correct. However the `const char*` will be automatically cast to `const unsigned char *` and marking the vars as unsigned ensures that sign extension will not happen during indexing. This is valid in c in particular as arguments are not checked by the compiler. However if the user of the function ends up with compiler warnings an explicit cast may be done.

Comment: This code is premature optimization. Assuming that you have 256 byte of RAM available, you can just create a 256 byte char array, and get rid of the bitshift operations. I do not see that we should assume we are memory limited according to the OP.

Comment: That would required far more memory to be initialized too zero killing the speed and surely blow out the L1 cache of the processor further hurting performance. furthermore this memory is allocated on the stack and most threads do not have a lot of stack space <=1MiB is common and stack sizes as low as <=8KiB is not unheard of thus using a 256 byte array is more likely to blow up your stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
int my_strspn(const char *str1,const char *str2){
int i,k,counter=0;
for(i=0;str1[i]!='\0';i++){
 if(counter != i) break;
 for(k=0;str2[k]!='\0';k++){
  if(str1[i]==str2[k])
   counter++;
 }
}
 return counter;
}
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect: `my_strspn("a", "aa")` returns 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation of `strspn()` would iterate on the first string, as long as it finds the corresponding character in the second string:

```c
#include <string.h>
size_t strspn(const char *str, const char *chars) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (str[i] && strchr(chars, str[i]))
        i++;
    return i;
}
```

Given that you are not allowed to call `strchr()`, here is a naive native implementation:

```c
size_t strspn(const char *str, const char *chars) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; chars[j] != str[i]; j++) {
            if (chars[j] == '\0')
                return i; // char not found, return index so far
        }
    }
    return i;  // complete string matches, return length
}
```

Scanning the second string repeatedly can be costly. Here is an alternative that combines different methods depending on the length of `chars`, assuming 8-bit bytes:

```c
size_t strspn(const char *str, const char *chars) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char c = chars[0];

    if (c != '\0') {  // if second string is empty, return 0
        if (chars[1] == '\0') {
            // second string has single char, use a simple loop
            while (str[i] == c)
                i++;
        } else {
            // second string has more characters, construct a bitmap
            unsigned char x, bits[256 / 8] = { 0 };
            for (i = 0; (x = chars[i]) != '\0'; i++)
                bits[x >> 3] |= 1 << (x & 7);
            // iterate while characters are found in the bitmap
            for (i = 0; (x = str[i]), (bits[x >> 3] & (1 << (x & 7))); i++)
                continue;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup table (a poor man's set) for all possible ASCII chars, and just lookup each character in `str`. This is worst case `O(max(N,M))`, where `N` is the number of characters in `str` and `M` is the number of characters in `chars`.

```
#include <string.h>

size_t strspn(const char *str, const char *chars) {
  int i;
  char ch[256] = {0};

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(chars); i++) {
    ch[chars[i]] = 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    if (ch[str[i]] == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return i;
}
```

This could also be solved without using `strlen` at all, assuming both strings are zero-terminated. The disadvantage of this solution is that one needs 256 bytes of memory for the lookup table.

Answer (score -1):

Without touching a C-compiler for the last couple of years. From the top of my head something like this should work:

```
int spn = 0;
while(*str++ != '\0')
{
  char *hay = chars;
  bool match = false;
  while(*hay++ != '\0')
  {
     if(*hay == *str)
     {
       match = true;
       break;
     }
  }

  if(match)
     spn++;
  else
     return spn;
}
return spn;
```

Comment: The code is flawed: you increment `hay` before testing `*hay == *str`. The first character of `chars` is always ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Well, implementing a standard library for my OS, here is my solution (C++).

```
KCSTDLIB_API_FUNC(size_t DECL_CALL strspn(const char * str1, const char * str2))
{
size_t count = 0;
auto isin = [&](char c)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; str2[x]; x++)
    {
        if (c == str2[x])
            return true;
    };
    return false;
};
for (; isin(str1[count]); count++);
return count;
}
```